# Implementation of the Minimum Stop Algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge

I started taking the Algorithm design class from Coursera. So into the third week they talk about Greedy algorithms and walks through a sample problem.

This is the Problem Statement that I could find which was close.

> Professor Midas drives an automobile from Newark to Reno along
>   Interstate 80. His car’s gas tank, when full, holds enough gas to
>   travel ‘d’ miles, and his map gives the distances between gas stations
>   on his route. The professor wishes to make as few stops as possible
>   along the way. The problem is to find an efficient method by which
>   Professor Midas can determine at which gas stations he should stop,
>   and prove that the strategy adopted yields an optimal solution.

The INPUT: an Array containing the Distance of each gas station from the Starting Point , and an integer that contains the maximum distance that the car can go with full tank of gas.

OUTPUT: The Minimum Number of Stops that the Car must make at each gas station to make a successful trip.

Here's the Code

```js
   /*
    * Week 3 , Algorythm Design Course Coursera
    *
    * Design an algorythm that computes the minimum Number of Refills that a car must make to reach
    * the destination .
    *
    * INPUT :
    *       An Integer Array giving the distance of the GasStations from the Starting point ,
    *       An Integer that gives the maximum distance that the car can travel on a full refill
    *
    *  OUTPUT:
    *      The Minimum Number of refills , that the car must make.
    */

   var getLeastRefills = function(stationDist, maxDistance) {
     var curPos = 1;
     var minRefill = 0;
     var curDistance = maxDistance;
     var numRefillStations = (stationDist.length - 1);

     while (curPos <= (numRefillStations)) {
       for (; stationDist[curPos] <= curDistance; curPos += 1);

       if (curPos > numRefillStations) return minRefill;

       curPos -= 1;
       minRefill += 1;
       curDistance = stationDist[curPos] + maxDistance;
     }

     if (stationDist[curPos] < curDistance)
       minRefill += 1;

     return minRefill;
   };

    // Test Cases
   console.log(getLeastRefills([0, 200, 375, 550, 750, 950], 400));
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, your project question asks for an array of stops to refill out as output. As for a way to help improve your code, your solution is already O(n) which is just about as good as it gets (Good work!). Hyper-optimizations that only improve your code by a constant factor generally aren't worth the time to program, especially in such a high level language as JavaScript.

Comment: The Code worked for One or two test cases . But i was unsure whether it     really works. Thanks.

Comment: One problem your code has is that it goes into an infinite loop when there is no solution (specifically if there is ever a distance greater than the tank size: [0, 100, 700, 950]). This can be annoying for someone testing out your code (me having to close my web browser from the task manager).